# Issues using PHP !isset and functions

Tags: php, function, isset

I am trying to use PHP !isset and a function to check if the any fields submitted from a HTML form are empty, and if so kill (exit) the script. Only the code I have currently oddly skips right over my !issets and continues. +'s to anyone who can figure this out. :)

```
// Get fields from HTML form
$Name = $_POST["Name"];
$Email = $_POST["Email"];
$Subject = $_POST["Subject"];
$Message = $_POST["Message"];

// Check to make sure no fields are empty
// If any fields are empty dumps script to fieldsmissing()
// If all fields are filled, continued to write actual email
if (!isset($Name)) {fieldsmissing(); };
if (!isset($Email)) {fieldsmissing(); };
if (!isset($Subject)) {fieldsmissing(); };
if (!isset($Message)) {fieldsmissing(); };

function fieldsmissing () {
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isset just checks whether a variable is set and not null, not whether it's blank. Try something like:

```
if (!$Name) {fieldsmissing(); }
if (!$Email) {fieldsmissing(); }
if (!$Subject) {fieldsmissing(); }
if (!$Message) {fieldsmissing(); }
```

Comment: +1 for having a negative rating on a perfectly good answer. This answer actually explains more than the answer with votes up

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice Thanks for the help!; Pierre's function before calling it idea was valid as well. I will +1 you guys once I have the rep to do so. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function fieldsmissing () { // to declare before calling it
  exit;
}

// Get fields from HTML form
if (!isset($_POST["Name"])) {fieldsmissing(); };
if (!isset($_POST["Email"])) {fieldsmissing(); };
if (!isset($_POST["Subject"])) {fieldsmissing(); };
if (!isset($_POST["Message"])) {fieldsmissing(); };

$Name = $_POST["Name"];
$Email = $_POST["Email"];
$Subject = $_POST["Subject"];
$Message = $_POST["Message"];

// then use $Name etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
php5 -r '$x="";if(isset($x)){print "isset\n";}'
```

returns:

```
isset
```

isset gives true for empty strings.

`empty()` can be much more useful. php.net/empty

Answer (score 0):

`$Name = $_POST["Name"];` will cause a warning if `$_POST["Name"]` is not available from the form.

You should probably do this instead:

`$Name = ( isset( $_POST["Name"] ) ? $_POST["Name"] : '' );`

if ( empty( $Name ) )
{
fieldsmissing();
}

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `isset` to check if filed was filled because it'll return `true` on empty string!

Instead use `empty()` function.

```
if (!isset($_POST['Name']) || empty($_POST['Name'])) {fieldsmissing(); }
```

Also, you don't have to use `;` after `}`.